# in ruby on rails how can I queu the job one by one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a big problem, I try to queu job one by one in a queu in ruby on rails.
I really need that the controller dont access at the same time to a liste of function because it is a long process and it use the databases during. If two time the process is started at same time (or little differences) it will be conflict in my data.

Thanks for your help,

Pierre

Comment: what version of rails are you using. You can try something like https://github.com/resque/resque

Comment: Its pretty unclear what you are asking but `perform_now` will run the job immediately and block the execution of the other jobs. Otherwise it depends on what [backend](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#backends) is actually running the queue. https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/Execution.html

Answer (score 0):

the most easy why is to put a static attribute in class

```
class MyJob
   @@locked=0
   def perform(*args)
    while @@locked==1 do
        sleep(0.2)
    end
    @@locked=1
    # your code here
    @@locked=0
  end
end
```